# How to subtract a shape from an image in CALayer?

Tags: ios

I'm building an custom view which includes an image and a badge. The picture shows my desired result.

I can easily achieve this with Sketch, but programming is much harder.

I can't find subtract operation in CALayer and UIBezierPath, so I have no idea how to create a clipped shape to mask the image.

#### What I want

[image]

#### What I have now

[image]

```swift
class PetAvatarView: UIView {

    var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            layer.contents = image?.cgImage
        }
    }

    private let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        maskLayer.frame = layer.bounds

        // image
        let imageMaskRadius = bounds.width / 2
        let imageMaskCenter = CGPoint(x: imageMaskRadius, y: imageMaskRadius)

        let imageMaskPath = UIBezierPath()
        imageMaskPath.addArc(withCenter: imageMaskCenter, radius: imageMaskRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

        let badgeMaskRadius = bounds.width / 5
        let badgeMaskCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - badgeMaskRadius, y: bounds.maxY - badgeMaskRadius)
        let badgeMaskPath = UIBezierPath()
        badgeMaskPath.addArc(withCenter: badgeMaskCenter, radius: badgeMaskRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)

        let path = imageMaskPath
        path.append(badgeMaskPath.reversing())
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I have no idea how to create a clipped shape to mask the image

Yes you do! You just said it yourself. You create a shape with clipping and use it to mask the image. The problem with your code is that you don't actually *do* any clipping.

Here's an example without the badge, to show how to take a circular "bite" out of the circular mask on the image:

[image]

How was that done? Well, I started with an image view displaying the kittens image. Then I gave that image view a mask. The mask looks like this (if you could see a mask):

[image]

So now the only question is how to draw that mask. Obviously, we do it by filling the large circle. But before we do that, we create a *clipping* path consisting of the small circle (at the lower right) plus the bounding box of the whole mask. Thus the large circle ends up clipped into that region.

Note that the badge drawing itself, the red circle, now cannot be a subview or sublayer of the image view, because we just masked out that region! However, that's not a difficult issue; there just needs to be another view in the story.

[image]

Comment: Lovely kitties! Thanks for your answer, I finally realize the feature.